# Java not able to load a class from class path

Tags: java, jar, classpath, javac

I have added a jar to my class path like:

```
export CLASSPATH="/Users/myname/.m2/repository/org/testng/testng/7.3.0/testng-7.3.0.jar";
```

and when I echo it, I get that jar.

However, I am running my jar like:

```
java -cp target/TestNgExample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:myname org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

but I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestNG
```

So as you see, I added that jar to the class path but still unable to use it.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: The use of the `CLASSPATH` environment variables is strong discouraged.

However, [as documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/man/java.html#standard-options-for-java) providing the `-cp` (or `--class-path`)  parameter on the command line overrides the CLASSPATH content

> Specifying classpath overrides any setting of the CLASSPATH environment variable. If the class path option isn't used and classpath isn't set, then the user class path consists of the current directory (.).

---

To include the TestNG jar file into your classpath, include it in the -cp parameter:

```
java -cp target/TestNgExample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/myname/.m2/repository/org/testng/testng/7.3.0/testng-7.3.0.jar org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Comment: What can I do to use class path environment?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: you need to remove the `-cp` parameter from your command line. But I would really recommend to not set CLASSPATH at all. It's much better to always specify the application specific classpath by using the `-cp` parameter

Comment: Maybe I can pass the two jars to this -cp. I tried this java -cp first.jar;second.jar but didn't work. do you know how?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: you need to list all jar files your application needs with the `-cp` parameter

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: the separator depends on which OS you are on. On Windows the separator is `;` (so what you posted should work). On everything else (including Linux and MacOS X) it is `:`, so you'd use `-cp first.jar:second.jar`.